# Xero OAuth2 without a server

Tags: xero-api

I have a legacy system that can make get, put and post requests over https

I don't have a server running to respond to a callback

Has anybody found a solution to getting the verifier and then 'doing' a transaction using only some combination of client id, client secret, username and password?

Thanks for any input

Comment: I don't think there's a need to have a server running, though I haven't tried it personally yet. I asked about whether specifying the URL meant I had to open ports on my clients router, and I was told it did not, which suggests to me that it is not attempting to open an incoming port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use some other method for doing the initial user authorization to get a refresh token. The good news is that this only needs to be done once.

Then, store that refresh token (along with the client id and secret) somewhere that your app can securely access it. Your app can then use the refresh token to get an access token (and a new refresh token that you'll need to store for next time) and make API calls.

The quickest way to do the user authorization is probably using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) (and you can follow our [tutorial here](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/tools/postman)). Otherwise you could modify one of our [sample apps](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/libraries/overview) in your preferred language.

Comment: Thanks Adam - not what I wanted to hear, but life is never simple :)  I've modified a sample app (the ASP) and printed the access and refresh tokens to the console - I can cut and paste the values for future use by our app - bit of a pain when setting up a dozen different systems but it works! Guess this is the answer but I don't seem able to mark it as such :(